# What changes to be made in standalone.xml file to exclude a particular directory from getting auto deployed in JBoss Server[Wildfly 9xx]

Tags: java, xml, jboss, wildfly

I have a requirement in WildFly server to stop auto deploying the directory if there are any changes in the file.
**The problem is I want to exclude a particular folder from getting auto deployed,not the whole directory**.

I tried to add another deployment scanner same as the default one by changing the path but didn't succeed.Please suggest me what changes to be made in standalone.xml. 
Thanks in advance.

default deployment scanner

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0">
    <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="1" auto-deploy-zipped="true" auto-deploy-exploded="true" runtime-failure-causes-rollback="${jboss.deployment.scanner.rollback.on.failure:false}"/>
</subsystem>
```

new deployment scanner added

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0">
    <deployment-scanner path="deployments/demo/dist"  relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="1" auto-deploy-zipped="false" auto-deploy-exploded="false" runtime-failure-causes-rollback="${jboss.deployment.scanner.rollback.on.failure:false}"/>
</subsystem>
```

Getting this Exception

---

```
12:01:26,611 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0055: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:131)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:347)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:271)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[165,62]
Message: WFLYCTL0069: Duplicate subsystem declaration
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.parseServerProfile(StandaloneXml.java:1195)
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readServerElement_1_4(StandaloneXml.java:457)
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:144)
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:106)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:123)
```

Comment: you don't need to add whole new subsystem, just add extra deployment-scanner element

Comment: @ctomc I tried as you said but still if I add something inside some-folder, server is restarting.I want server to ignore this change.            `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0"><deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5" auto-deploy-zipped="true" auto-deploy-exploded="true" /><deployment-scanner name="new-scanner" path="deployments/demo.war/WEB-INF/dist/some-folder" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="1" auto-deploy-zipped="false" auto-deploy-exploded="false"/></subsystem>`

Comment: why don't you just deploy via cli in that case? and forget about deployment-scanner all together

Answer (score 1):

You've got two subsystems now called `deployment-scanner`. You only need one subsystem entry.

I'd also advise you to use the web console or CLI to add a new deployment scanner. With CLI the command would look something like the following.

```
/subsystem=deployment-scanner/scanner=custom:add(path=deployments/demo/dist, relative-to=jboss.server.base.dir, scan-interval=1, auto-deploy-zipped=false, auto-deploy-exploded=false, runtime-failure-causes-rollback="${jboss.deployment.scanner.rollback.on.failure:false}")
```